# ' Jest encountered an unexpected token { ' error on react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I can't seem to get past this issue. I have tried everything(so many!) I could find of this issue online but it just doesn't seem to fix. Here are the configurations

package.json

```
    {
      "scripts": {
        "test": "jest --no-cache",
        "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.5.4",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.5",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.4",
        "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
        "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
        "babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.3.4",
        "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.2.0",
        "babel-plugin-recharts": "^1.2.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-imports": "^2.0.0",
        "flow-bin": "^0.106.1",
        "flow-typed": "^2.6.1",
        "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
        "jest": "^24.9.0",
        "lodash-webpack-plugin": "^0.11.5",
        "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
        "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
        "webpack": "^4.35.3",
        "webpack-async-chunk-names-plugin": "^0.1.1",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.3.2",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.5",
        "webpack-dashboard": "^3.0.7",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.2",
        "webpack-merge": "^4.2.1"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.2.0",
        "@material-ui/icons": "^4.2.1",
        "clsx": "1.0.2",
        "fg-loadcss": "^2.1.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.15",
        "react": "^16.8.6",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
        "react-gradient": "^1.0.1",
        "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
        "recharts": "^1.6.2",
        "redux": "^4.0.4",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
      }
    }
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  "testRegex": "((\\.|/*.)(test))\\.js?$",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(js|ts)x?$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest"
  }
}
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true)

  const presets = [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {"modules": false}],
    ["@babel/preset-flow", {"all": true}],
    "@babel/preset-react",
  ]
  const plugins = [
    "lodash",
    "recharts",
    //"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["./"],
      "alias": {
        "projectRoot": "./",
        "src": "./src/",
      },
    }],
    ["transform-imports", {
      "@material-ui/core": {
        //supports only upto level 2 (@material-ui/core/Tabs/TabIndicator <- level 3 not supported)
        "transform": "@material-ui/core/${member}",
      },
    }],
  ]

  return {
    presets,
    plugins
  }
}
```

the error I get

```
Details:

   src/helpers/__tests__/utils.test.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import { getDateString, getTimeString } from "../utils";
                                                                                                    ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
```

This has been extremely frustrating to see nothing works on it. I have tried uncountable things so far but it does not seem to work. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: seem you ts config doesnt use the babel-jest correctly ! try use `"transform": {
    "^.+\\.(js|ts)x?$": "babel-jest"
  }`

Comment: @SpringerF that does not work either

Comment: You're using typescript or only babel ?

Comment: I forgot to mention I am not using typescript, just babel with js

Comment: not sur but , whther your config jest not loaded , or babel-jest isn't recognized

in the  package.json 
try adding the location of your jst config`--config ./jest.config.json` as folow
    `{
      "scripts": {
        "test": "jest --config ./jest.config.json --no-cache",
        "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
      },...`

Answer (score 0):

> import { getDateString, getTimeString } from "../utils";

this line indicates that your babel is not transpiling es module syntax

try `module: 'cjs'`

```
  const presets = [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {"modules": 'cjs'}],
    ["@babel/preset-flow", {"all": true}],
    "@babel/preset-react",
  ]
```